# AttributeError: 'class' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am running into this error while executing my python code:

```
Error:  line 20, in _readBookList  
if bkID < cur_node.bkID: AttributeError: 'bookNode' object has no attribute 'bkID'
```

The `input.txt` file has the following data:

```
100,2  
101,3  
102,5
```

Code:

```
class bookNode:
    def __init__(self, bkID, availCount):
        self.bookID = bkID
        self.avCntr = availCount
        self.ChkOutCntr = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def readBookList(self, bkID, availCount):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
        else:
            self._readBookList(bkID,availCount,self.root)

    def _readBookList(self,bkID, availCount, cur_node):
        if bkID < cur_node.bkID:
            if cur_node.left == None:
                cur_node.left = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
                # cur_node.left_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                self._readBookList(bkID, availCount, cur_node.left)
        elif bkID > cur_node.bkID:
            if cur_node == None:
                cur_node = bookNode(bkID,availCount)
                # cur_node.right_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                self._readBookList(bkID,availCount, cur_node.right)
        else:
            print("ID already in tree!")

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root != None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self, cur_node):
        if cur_node != None:
            self._print_tree(cur_node.left)
            print(cur_node.bkID)
            self._print_tree(cur_node.right)
tree = Tree()

f = open("input.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    print(x)
    bookDetails = x.split(",")
    tree.readBookList(bookDetails[0], bookDetails[1])
    # _readBookList
f.close()
tree.print_tree()
```

Comment: Thank you all for the support.
Below are issues in code:
I have missed 2 things in the original code   
1. bkid should be replaced with bookID in the lines 21 and 27 (ie., if bkID < cur_node.bookID: and elif bkID > cur_node.bookID:)  
2. In the line 28 should replace cur_node with cur_node.right.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo error,

```
if bkID < cur_node.bkID:
```

should be :

```
if bkID < cur_node.bookID:
```

Check the updated code :

```
class bookNode:
    def __init__(self, bkID, availCount):
        self.bookID = bkID
        self.avCntr = availCount
        self.ChkOutCntr = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def readBookList(self, bkID, availCount):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
        else:
            self._readBookList(bkID,availCount,self.root)

    def _readBookList(self,bkID, availCount, cur_node):
        if cur_node != None :
            if bkID < cur_node.bookID:
                if cur_node.left == None:
                    cur_node.left = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
                    # cur_node.left_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
                else:
                    self._readBookList(bkID, availCount, cur_node.left)
            elif bkID > cur_node.bookID:
                if cur_node == None:
                    cur_node = bookNode(bkID,availCount)
                    # cur_node.right_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
                else:
                    self._readBookList(bkID,availCount, cur_node.right)
            else:
                print("ID already in tree!")

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root != None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self, cur_node):
        if cur_node != None:
            self._print_tree(cur_node.left)
            print(cur_node.bookID)
            self._print_tree(cur_node.right)
tree = Tree()

f = open("input.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    print(x)
    bookDetails = x.split(",")
    tree.readBookList(bookDetails[0], bookDetails[1])
    # _readBookList
f.close()
tree.print_tree()
```

The problem is with the line, `self._readBookList(bkID,availCount, cur_node.right)`, here you are not checking if `cur_node.right` is not `None` or not. I have updated it.

Comment: Thank you Roshin

Comment: new Error:   if bkID < cur_node.bookID:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bookID'

Comment: can you please help

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the name you are calling is an argument to the `__init__`, not an attribute. to fix this you just need to change `*.bkID` to `*.bookID`

Comment: Thank you. I am facing a new error now. Can you please help.  New Error: if bkID < cur_node.bookID: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bookID'

Comment: @thunderbolt489 could you please specify what line?

Comment: line 20, in _readBookList    if bkID < cur_node.bookID:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bookID'

Comment: the reason is that, somehow, you are passing in `None` Pass in a  class that has that attribute, and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. I have missed 2 things in the original code
1. bkid should be replaced with bookID in the lines 21 and 27 (ie., if bkID < cur_node.bookID: and elif bkID > cur_node.bookID:)
2. In the line 28 should replace cur_node with cur_node.right.

Answer (score -1):

Because you spelled it wrong `cur_node` does not have `bkID` it is actually `bookID`.
Also, you forgot to add `cur_node.right = bookNode(bkID,availCount)` this line. Below is the complete code.

```
class bookNode:
    def __init__(self, bkID, availCount):
        self.bookID = bkID
        self.avCntr = availCount
        self.ChkOutCntr = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def readBookList(self, bkID, availCount):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
        else:
            self._readBookList(bkID,availCount,self.root)

    def _readBookList(self,bkID, availCount, cur_node):
        if bkID < cur_node.bookID: #HERE
            if cur_node.left == None:
                cur_node.left = bookNode(bkID, availCount)
                # cur_node.left_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                self._readBookList(bkID, availCount, cur_node.left)
        elif bkID > cur_node.bookID: #HERE
            if cur_node == None:
                cur_node = bookNode(bkID,availCount)
                # cur_node.right_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                cur_node.right = bookNode(bkID,availCount) #ADD THIS LINE
                self._readBookList(bkID,availCount, cur_node.right)
        else:
            print("ID already in tree!")

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root != None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self, cur_node):
        if cur_node != None:
            self._print_tree(cur_node.left)
            print(cur_node.bookID) #HERE
            self._print_tree(cur_node.right)
tree = Tree()

f = open("input.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    print(x)
    bookDetails = x.split(",")
    tree.readBookList(bookDetails[0], bookDetails[1])
    # _readBookList
f.close()
tree.print_tree()
```